# DrawingManager Here Maps Create Dynamic Polygon [Javascript v3]

Tags: here-api

I have some doubts here. I'm using version 3 of the JavaScript API Here Maps and I need to create an object in the same style as the Drawing Manager (http://biostall.com/demos/google-maps-v3-api-codeigniter-library/drawingmanager) available for Google Maps.

Basically it works so that the user click several times on the map and will be created a polygon defined by the user clicks. This polygon can be modified as the user will moving the position of the vertices of the polygon.

There is something ready to do that in Here or some code you can give me a direction on this issue?

My map basically follows the same idea of Here documentation:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform ({ 'app_id' 'MY_ID'
         'App_code' 'MY_APP_CODE'});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers = ();
var map = new H.Map (document.getElementById ( 'mapContainer'
       defaultLayers.normal.map);
```

Comment: I'm migrating from the Google Maps to Here Maps and also facing drawing problems with Here Maps — there are a lot of things which is missing in Here Maps, one of them is the analog of Google Map's Drawing Manager :(

Answer (score 1):

Well its June 2020 and there is still no built in "Drawing Manager" for Here maps but I did manage to get one working without rolling my own.

First use the leaflet.js library to produce the Here Maps https://leafletjs.com/ 
Then use a leaflet plugin for the Drawing functionality such as https://geoman.io/leaflet-geoman

Here is a working example, just replace the here maps api key.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free@latest/dist/leaflet-geoman.css" />
      <style>
         html,body{
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         }
         #mapContainer{
         width:100%;
         height:100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="mapContainer"></div>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/@geoman-io/leaflet-geoman-free@latest/dist/leaflet-geoman.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         var map = L.map('mapContainer', {
           center: [  -29.529838,  24.810199],
           zoom: 6
         });
         var HERE_MAPS_API_KEY = "xxxxxxx"; //replace with your API Key 
         var layer = L.tileLayer("https://2.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day.transit/{z}/{x}/{y}/512/png8?apiKey="+HERE_MAPS_API_KEY+"&ppi=320" , { styleId: 997 }).addTo(map);
         map.pm.addControls({
            position: 'topleft'
         });
         map.attributionControl.addAttribution('&copy; HERE MAPS');
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no ready-made functionality for dynamic polygons. You would have to implement it from scratch. To get started you would probably look at the following example for the user interaction:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/markers/draggable-marker

When you have that set up as you need it (adding markers, moving marker, removing markers, etc), you can take a look at this example to figure out the stuff about polygons:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/geoshapes/polygon-on-the-map

As far as I can tell from the API reference you should be able to recreate the strip and set it on the polygon, whenever a marker is dragged. The polygon should repaint then.

https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-polygon.html#h-map-polygon__setstrip

Comment: Well, it is December 2018 and still there is no anything like Drawing Manager in Here Maps. What a disappointment :(